# The number $2$ is a real root of $z^3=8$. Find the distance $|2-w|$ if $w$ is a complex root of $z^3=8$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> > Question: The number $2$ is a real root of $z^3=8$. Find the distance $|2-w|$ if $w$ is a complex root of $z^3=8$ leaving your answer in surd form.

---

What I have attempted:

$$z^3=8$$

$$ \frac{z^3}{8} = 1$$

$$ \left(\frac{z}{2} \right)^3 = 1 $$

$$ \frac{z}{2} = \omega^2 , \omega , 1 $$

$$ z = -1±\sqrt{3}i  , 2$$

Plotting this on geogebra:

[image]

I see that it forms an equilateral triangle , how can i find this distance between the 2 complex roots $ z = -1±\sqrt{3}i$ ?

The answer is $2\sqrt{3}$ but I am not how this was reached with the distance formula?

Comment: The equilateral triangle is inscribed in a circle of radius _______? Though modulus of $2-(-1\pm\sqrt3i)$ should also be quick.

Comment: @Macavity How do i find the radius.. also is there a formula to find the distance between 2 complex numbers. Like there is a distance formula?

Comment: The formula is exactly analogous to distance on the Cartesian plane, just as you're plotting it.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial of $w$ and $\bar w$ is $z^2+2z+4$. On the other hand, the square of this distance is, by Vieta's relations:
$$(2-w)(2-\bar w)=4-2(w+\bar w)+w\bar w=4-2(-2)+4=12$$
 whence $\;\lvert 2-w\rvert=2\sqrt 3$.

Comment: Thanks for that , I was wondering how you would get the answer through the distance formula?

Comment: Solving explicitly and a little help from Pythagoras…

Answer (score 0):

$$z^3=2^3\implies z=2e^{2m\pi i/3}$$  where $m=-1,0,1$

$m=0\implies z=?$

Now $F=2-2e^{2m\pi i/3}=2\left(1-\cos\dfrac{2m\pi}3-i\sin\dfrac{2m\pi}3\right)$

Using Double Angle formula,
$F=-2i\sin\dfrac{m\pi}3\left(\cos\dfrac{m\pi}3-i\sin\dfrac{m\pi}3\right)$

$\implies| F|=2\left|\sin\dfrac{m\pi}3\right|=2\sin\dfrac\pi3=?$ as $m=\pm1$

Answer (score 0):

Given you have found the roots explicitly:
$$|2-(-1\pm\sqrt3i)|=|3\mp\sqrt3i|=\sqrt{(3)^2+(\sqrt3)^2}=2\sqrt3$$

In general for a complex number, $|z|=\sqrt{z\overline{z}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the 2 complex roots $z = -1±\sqrt{3}i$ is $2\sqrt{3}$ because each root is $\sqrt{3}$ units from the Real axis. As you noted, the triangle is equilateral, so the distance between all three roots is $2\sqrt{3}$.